# Fourier transform of a triangular pulse

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I've been practicing some Fourier transform questions and stumbled on the following one.

---

[image: question]

---

To start off, I defined the Fourier transform for this function by taking integral from $-\tau$ to $0$ and $0$ to $\tau$, as shown below

[image: starting it off]

from that, I evaluated the first integral and got the following result

[image: first integral]

then followed by the second integral

[image: second integral]

From the two integrals, I tried to solve for $X(\omega)$ by summing the two integrals

[image]

Now, this is where I got stuck. I am not sure how to express this as the required answer. Am I missing some small details or is it some basic algebra?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Sinc function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) is tricky, because there are two of them. It seems your book uses the convention
$$\operatorname{sinc} x = \frac{\sin (\pi x)}{\pi x}$$
The desired answer is 
$$X(\tau) = \tau\frac{\sin^2 (\omega \tau/2)}{(\omega \tau/2)^2}  = \frac{4}{\omega^2 \tau }\sin^2 (\omega \tau/2) =\frac{2}{\omega^2 \tau }(1-\cos \omega \tau) $$
Which is what you have, since $e^{j\omega\tau}+e^{-j\omega\tau}=2\cos  \omega\tau$.

Comment: And i was so close too haha, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Bookend how can we generalize that? say for support [-a, a] and triangle height of b?

Comment: @ThunderWiring, check the [Fourier transform properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Basic_properties)

Answer (score 1):

Continue from what you have got:
$$\frac{2-(e^{j\omega \tau} + e^{-j\omega \tau)}}{\omega^2 \tau} = \frac{2-2\cos(\omega \tau)}{\omega^2 \tau} = \frac{2(1-\cos(\omega \tau))}{\omega^2 \tau} $$
Recall that
$$1-\cos(\omega \tau) = 2 \sin^2 (\frac{\omega \tau}{2})$$
Thus
$$\frac{2(1-\cos(\omega \tau))}{\omega^2 \tau} = \frac{4\sin^2 (\frac{\omega \tau}{2})}{\omega^2 \tau}$$
Rearrange by multiplying the numerator and the denominator by $\frac{\tau}{4}$

$$\frac{4\sin^2 (\frac{\omega \tau}{2})}{\omega^2 \tau} \cdot \frac{\frac{\tau}{4}}{\frac{\tau}{4}} = \tau \left[\frac{\sin (\frac{\omega \tau}{2})}{\frac{\omega \tau}{2}}\right]^2$$

And recall that
$$\mathrm{sinc}(\frac{\omega \tau}{2}) = \frac{\sin (\frac{\omega \tau}{2})}{\frac{\omega \tau}{2}}$$

Therefore, 
$$\mathfrak{F}[\mathrm{tri}(\frac{t}{\tau}] = \tau  \mathrm{sinc}^2(\frac{\omega \tau}{2})$$

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way to arrive at the expression involving the cosine term is to consider the symmetry of the triangular pulse. Since it is an even function, multiplication by exp(-jwt) is equivalent to multiplying by coswt, since the sine term will go to zero. Then we get lesser number of integrals to evaluate and the same expression involving [1-cos(omega.tau)]can be obtained much more easily.

Hope this helps.