# Counterexample of Gnedenko in probability theory (about an integral of $f(x) = \frac{1-\cos x}{\pi x^2}$ and a series)

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

Consider 
$$f(x) = \frac{1-\cos x}{\pi x^2}.$$

How can I prove the following?

> $$G(t) = \int_\mathbb{R} e^{itx}f(x) dx = \begin{cases}1-|t|, &|t| \le 1 \\ 0, &|t|>1 \end{cases}$$
>   and $$G(t) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{4}{\pi^2} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\cos((2k-1)t\pi)}{(2k-1)^2} \quad \forall t \in [-1,1]$$

Comment: Do you know about the Fourier transform and its convolution properties (can be used for the first one) and Fourier series and their convergence (can be used for the second identity). I did not check the calculations, but it should be straight forward.

Comment: @mickep How would you do that?

Comment: First one,  http://www.thefouriertransform.com/pairs/triangle.php ... Second one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/898170/fourier-transform-of-a-triangular-pulse

Comment: I was just asking if you know Fourier methods. If you don't, I don't know how you are supposed to show these formulas. If you do, then it is a pretty straightforward, but tiresome calculation.

Comment: For the first identity you can follow the argument of robjohn answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1157772/integral-int-infty-infty-frac-sin2xx2-eixdx?rq=1

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1108138/321264